# Making music boxes project from Coder Projects, boxes don't seem to register mousedown

Tags: javascript, css

In order to better understand Javascript, I'm making the music boxes project offered by [Coder Projects](https://googlecreativelab.github.io/coder-projects/projects/music_boxes/). I've followed all of the instructions and the site looks like it should and the boxes do all of the things they should when the mouse hovers over them. However, clicking on the boxes doesn't change the color like it should, nor do the music notes play. I have the color change coded like so for all the notes:

```
#c:active {
background-color:#db1d2d;   
}
```

The music tones are coded in javascript like so:

```
$('#c').mousedown(function(){
    cNote.currentTime = 0;
    cNote.play();
});
```

The fact that both of these are going wrong, combined with the fact that they seem to be exactly like they should be in the instructions, leads me to believe that for some reason the site isn't registering mouse presses, but I can't think of why this would be. Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> However, clicking on the boxes doesn't change the color like it should, nor do the music notes play.

It's important to understand the distinction between the `mousedown` and `click` events.

`mousedown` - Is fired when the mouse is being pressed

`click` - Is fired after the mouse is released.

You need to specify multiple event listeners. You are only listening for the `mousedown` event, which is why the `click` event isn't getting triggered. use `on(event)` syntax.

```
$('#c').on("mousedown click", function(){
    cNote.currentTime = 0;
    cNote.play();
});
```

Comment: I don't have any click events. My problem is none of my mousedown events are triggering when I press the mouse button. I'm also not sure how this helps with the css :active elements not triggering.